# Storing a value inside the function to the outside

Tags: swift

In swift UIKit

```
import UIKit

class TapQuestions: UIViewController  {
    
var linkString : String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        ObserveTable()        
}
func ObserveTable () {

    ObservesTap().GETAPI { arr in
        self.arrAPI += arr
        
        if self.arrAPI.count > 0 {
            self.linkString = self.arrAPI[0].url
            
        }
    }
 }
```

Here is this func ( ObserveTable )

I brought my value through the ( if )

and store it in the variable ( linkString )

But when I print var linkString from inside the if
I see the value is there

But when I print it outside the IF
I see that the value is empty

I want to store the value in the variable and use it outside the if

I did not find a similar topic to my problem on the site, please help

Comment: What's `arrAPI`? What is the logic here, you are always getting value from first index here?

Comment: It's the data from the database

Comment: The data is present without a problem inside the if

Comment: What's initial value of arrAPI?

Comment: It's a link I want to use

Comment: It comes as String

Comment: Try replacing `arrAPI +=` to `arrAPI =`

Comment: It's the same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239989/discussion-between-rob-and-bdriii).

Comment: Could you edit the code a bit and show where/what self.arrAPI is? And what do you mean by outside the IF? adding the print statement would be nice, so we can know where/when you try to access linkString.